How to resolve Next.js SSR Docker container to communicate with nginx from host machine?
I've got an API (Laravel) and a UI (Next.js SSR) being served via nginx using Docker. From the client side everything is working as intended, I'm able to hit the pages and call the API without issues. However, when I try leveraging the server side aspect of Next.js for data fetching it fails.
The following is my docker-compose.yaml:
name: my-app

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      target: dev
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - api
      - app

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./app
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www
    networks:
      - mynetwork

I then have the following server blocks setup for my nginx configuration:
server {
    server_name myapp.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    server_name api.myapp.localhost;
    root /var/www/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

Now the problem code, in my app/layout.tsx:
export default async function Layout({children}: DefaultProps): Promise<ReactNode> {
    const session = await fetch();

    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
            <meta
                name="viewport"
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
            />
            <link
                rel="icon"
                type="image/ico"
                href="/img/favicon/favicon.ico"
            />
        </head>
        <body>
        <UserProvider session={session}>
            <Header/>
            <main>
                <AuthModal/>
                {children}
            </main>
            <Footer/>
        </UserProvider>
        </body>
        </html>
    );
}

Where the fetch() call is a GET request hitting http://api.myapp.localhost/... but Next.js responds with an error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

I presume this is because the container itself doesn't know the hostname being referenced because that's handled by host machine and nginx handles the routing via the server names.
I can't directly pass the container name as part of the API endpoint request because the API is using fpm so it needs nginx.
I've tested this by transforming the server side call to an client side call and it works without issue and I couldn't find other questions which would point me in the right direction to solve this.
What's the fix?

If all of the front-end calls are going through the reverse proxy, do you need a host name at all?  Can you fetch() a path-only URL like /test.php, that will go to the same host and port as the current page?

@DavidMaze, to clarify, do you mean instead of matching hostname directly, match for a specific path? Because I've got it working now in a hacky way by making the API server block default and then matching the server_name by using the following pattern: *./v1 and that resolves it. Or do you mean something else?
